# Why a new 'merged' mesh is created when adding multiple loop cuts?

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects, geometry, loop

I'm just introduced to loop cuts which add more vertices to the mesh but for me it seems to be creating a new 'merged' mesh.

I have no clue why especially since I can account for all the the meshes in the outliner and there doesnt appear to be an extra duplicate. Extruding seems to work just fine but loop cuts just do this when I try to transform the mesh after the loop cut.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: you must have two meshes overlapping, perhaps try a Alt M > merge by distance before creating the loop cut

Comment: It looks like at some point you duplicated something somewhere. I can't tell if it's just that mesh (duped in edit mode), or another mesh (object) sitting in the same spot, which you selected in addition to the first one before entering edit mode (which is why you can still see the wireframe). My guess is the latter, based on the "Sprinkle L.001" in your outliner.

Comment: Hi and welcome! This is no regular forum rather a Q&A site so please always try to be specific in your title of the question which will make your question helpful to future visitors, I'd recommend read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask and take the [tour](https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn how this site works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Loop cuts](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/tools/loop.html) are inserted using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> or the *Loop Cut tool* in the [Toolbar](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/tools/toolbar.html#toolbar). Both tools are going to place an edge in a loop of faces and do *not* create any double geometry.

If you have double geometry after inserting a loopcut, it is there definitely not because of the loop cut, but because of some other mistake.

[image]

Comment: So i guess it just has to be that the original sprinkle I used also had a duplicate on top of it? cause I tried doing a loop cut on all the variants and they all had the same issue except the sphere which was added separately as a new UV Sphere.

Comment: It seems there can be no other explanation. You must have pressed Shift+D with everything selected in edit mode accidentally or something like that. You have to track and keep in mind every single thing you do or press in Blender because those operations always do something even if it is not visible. You could select all in edit mode with A and hit M followed by B to merge vertices by distance to deal with duplicate geometry if you need to correct this mistake.

Comment: @brockmann, thanks for taking the time to edit! :)

Comment: No problem, nice answer... glad I could help @MartynasŽiemys